# Zero size for svg file after extracting bootchart from journal

Tags: linux, svg

I have been working on optimization of boottime in Yocto platform. so I tried to use the systemd-bootchart to analize timings of various services .

After adding the init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart to the boot command line and starting the boot, Linux starts, loads the kernel. Journal file is created inside /run/log .
But while extracting bootchart from this journal i am getting zero size svg file.
I used below command for doing the same.

> $ journalctl -b --field=BOOTCHART > bootchart.svg

How will I get bootchart properly from journal?
Thank you for any help and insight into this problem.

Comment: did you open the file is there any data. check once?